# How to trigger visibility with checkbox in another usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have UserControl A and a DataGrid in Window W. The DataGrid has a UserControl B in the RowDetailsTemplate in one of its columns. A and B are in different .xaml files.

UserControl A has a checkbox (x:Name=OneMaterial), of which I want to use the property IsChecked to trigger the visibility of a StackPanel in UserControl B.

So I came up with this, for a trigger in the StackPanel:

```
  <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger                                
            Binding="{Binding ElementName=OneMaterial, Path=IsChecked,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Value="true">
             <Setter
                Property="Visibility"
                Value="Collapsed"/>
         </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
```

And of course this was too optimistic. I cannot use RelativeSource and ElementName together.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Are you sharing a ViewModel/DataContext between the two views?

Comment: No. A has a context that contains "segments", and B handles properties of ONE segment. So the datacontext of B is part of A's datacontext,

Comment: You can try to pass the CheckBox.IsChecked value through a CLR property in your Model class.

Comment: If they are both using the same datacontext that was bound to the Main Window, you could use:
    
Binding="{Binding ElementName=OneMaterial, Path=IsChecked,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"


That way it will navigate all the way to the parent window where you would have a common entry point

Comment: Nope. ElementName and RelativeSource don't go together: Sadly.